# handling stringstream errors with try/catch

Tags: c++, c++11

How can I handle the following exception without using if/else  ( only using try/catch):-

```
string S;
cin >> S;
stringstream ss(S);
int n;         
try {
   ss>>n;
   if(ss.fail()) throw (exception())
   else cout<<n;
} 
catch (const exception& e) { cout << "Bad String"<<endl;}
```

Comment: See the [`exceptions` method](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions).

Comment: Is throwing an exception really necessary? You can check for valid extraction like this: `if (ss >> n) {...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stream has an `exceptions` member function to tell it what condidions should throw exceptions. In this case, you just tell it to throw an exception on `fail`:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string S;
    cin >> S;
    stringstream ss(S);
    ss.exceptions(ios::failbit);

    int n;
    try {
        ss>>n;
        cout<<n;
    } 
    catch (const exception& e) { 
        cout << "Bad String\n";
    }
}
```

This turns out to be less useful that it might initially seem, but if that's what you want, this is how you do it.

Oh, and stop using `using namespace std;`. It's fraught with problems.

Comment: so what is the more useful way?

Comment: In a typical case, you read data in a loop, and check for successful reading as the loop's condition. Afterward, you sort out why it exited the loop, and log the error (or whatever) as appropriate.